# Craftercms: How to define a singleton service bean (written in groovy) in Spring?

Tags: java, groovy, content-management-system

I wrote a service (ZipService) which is being called from the Rest controllers.
I need the service to be instantiated only once and reuse it in every call.

Is there a way to define a singleton service bean written in groovy in the configuration and access it using the applicationContext object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use the site's own Spring application context to define singleton beans. Then in your script you can do `applicationContext.mybean` (mybean being your bean name) to retrieve the singleton. You can get more information on the applicationContext variable in http://docs.craftercms.org/en/latest/developers/custom-services-and-controllers.html and on defining Spring beans in http://docs.craftercms.org/en/latest/site-administrators/engine-site-configuration.html.

Comment: Documentation now has language and version support.  The URLs provided above should be updated:

http://docs.craftercms.org/en/latest/developers/custom-services-and-controllers.html

http://docs.craftercms.org/en/latest/site-administrators/engine-site-configuration.html